# Can enemies spawn on my roads?

Tags: timber-and-stone

I have a road that leads to the edge of the map.

[image]

It is protected by walls of cobblestone, but I am wondering: can enemies spawn either on the road or in the space between the road and the wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enemies Spawn by entering from the edges of the map, the rare chance of getting an enemy to spawn from that specific spot on the map seems very slim. So yes I would say its possible you'll get an enemy to spawn there.

What I would suggest is going into options and selecting, "pause if enemies are spotted" option. Although i recently find out if your forager doesnt spot the enemy and dies it still doesnt pause.

Answer (score 0):

I have definitively proven mobs can spawn on roads.
I have floating roads on all 4 edges and frequently I see dead enemies within 5 tiles of the edge (where they either had a melee with each other or a potential settler).
Not on my pc writing this so I had to take pictures rather than screens so apologies for the probably crappy look.
Using latest version (afaik) 1.18.15.

Hope this helps answer someone's query.

Edit can't get the picture to show, I hit upload and it does, finishes, then nothing.. My only option then is to hit cancel to get back to the screen with the post button.
For serious it's true through about the mobs & roads.